# How to pass a different url to the next VC with prepare for segue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I want to pass a different url to the next VC compared to which cell the user selected via my prepare segue but how can I do that ? Thanks !

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let idGenderMovie = gendersDataModel[indexPath.row].id
    let urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=&with_genres=\(idGenderMovie)"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMovies", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let showMovieFilteredVC = segue.destination as? ShowFilteredMovie else {return}
    showMovieFilteredVC.urlGender = //???
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that you had that information because the row in question was selected. But then you threw the information away by calling `tableView.deselectRow`. Why did you do that? Basically you're saying you need to know which row it was and then deliberately hiding from yourself which row it was! That's pretty silly.

Comment: Also you say `parseMovieGender(json: data)` but what happens to the _result_ of that call? I don't see you _doing_ anything with your new knowledge of the gender. Where did it go?

Comment: all right I understand better now, I edited my code, I still don't know how to pass my url to another VC depending on which row the user select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt says in his comment, you know which cell was selected in your `didSelectRowAt()` method. You extract a URL from your data model using the user's selected row, fetch some data from that URL, and then drop that information on the floor.

Instead, create an instance variable in your view controller, userSelectedRow, and set it in your didSelectRowAt() method. Then, in your prepareForSegue, use the selected row to fetch the info you need and pass it to your destination view controller.

### EDIT:

Or, as Matt suggests, don't save anything. Leave the row selected, and in `prepare(for:)`, interrogate your table view for its selected row, and use that to fetch your data.

By the way, if the URL is to a remote server, you should **not** read it using `Data(contentsOf:)`. That is a synchronous call that will block your user interface until it completes. You could cause your UI to freeze for up to 2 minutes trying to read data from a remote server with that call. (And that would cause your app to be killed as unresponsive.)

Comment: I really can't agree with this. You should _not_ save the selected row. The row is selected! If you don't mess things up, it will still be selected in `prepare(forSegue:)` and you can just ask the table what row it is and go from there.

Comment: @matt "The row is selected." Fair enough. Sometimes, though, you want the row to de-select after the user taps it, and have it act like a button. I guess that was what I was thinking when I read the OPs code.

Comment: I still can't agree. If you want the row to deselect, do it _after_ `prepare(forSegue:)`, not before. Actually the usual thing is to do it in `viewWillAppear`; that's what UITableViewController does.